# Drupal7 compared to Drupal6?

Tags: drupal

What are the differences between Drupal7 and Drupal6? What about theming?

Answer (score 4):

[The first alpha announcement](http://drupal.org/drupal-7.0-alpha1) provided a comprehensive list of high level improvements made since Drupal 6.

Theming wise you would want to be [checking out the docs](http://drupal.org/update/theme/6/7) around the differences between 6.x and 7.x